# Run batch file on remote machine using psExec in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, psexec

I can run the batch file from the command prompt like this

```
PsExec.exe \\remoteMachine "C:\Users\admin\test.bat"
```

I am trying to call the same above command using python

```
remoteCommand = r'C:\Users\username\test.bat' 
argList = ["PsExec.exe", remoteCommand]
out = subprocess.check_output(argList)
print "Output: ", out
```

But it throws an error shown below

```
The system cannot find the file specified.

PsExec could not start C:\Users\admin\test.bat:
.
.<Stacktrace present here>
.
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['PsExec.exe', 'C:\\Users\\admin\\test.bat']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Comment: Just my thought, maybe you need admin access to execute PsExec.exe which is not happening within Python script?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is running a batch file on a remote machine, you could use WMI instead of PSExec:

```
connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user='username', password='password')
startup = connection.Win32_ProcessStartup.new(ShowWindow=1)
connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine=batcmd, ProcessStartupInformation=startup)
```

Where "batcmd" is the full local path on the remote machine to the batch file (e.g. - "C:\\directory\\something.bat").

Answer (score 0):

In your argument list you don't indicate the remote machine you're calling. Maybe change your args list to:

```
argList = ["PsExec.exe", "\\\\remotemachine", remoteCommand]
```